# How to style title in Bootstrap select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using Bootstrap select (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for my dropdown boxes.

```
<select id="dataBox" name="dataBox" title="Select data" class="selectpicker form-control"></select>
```

However, the issue here is the title looks slightly different (font and color) from placeholders in input boxes in the surrounding area. Like shown below. Is there anyway to format the title instead of the placeholder?

This is a title

[image]

This is a placeholder

[image]

Comment: Can you share a live example? It would be useful to see these items in context and see what is causing the subtle differences.

Comment: This is a great question! +1 This is a great challenge because Bootstrap Select lacks an explicit class for when the title is visible on the button. (Which I think would be a nice feature)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap-select is tricky. The answer here is to do this:

```
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title='Select role'],
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title='Select role']:hover,
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title='Select role']:focus,
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title='Select role']:active {
    color: grey;
}
```

Comment: +1 As far as I can see, this is the best approach and amongst the very few options without introducing Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/), you're looking for this selector:

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle .filter-option {
    /* your custom stuff */
}
```

Title attribute gets placed into this element and acts as a placeholder:

```
<span class="filter-option pull-left">Select data</span>
```

Comment: Worth noting: this does style the visible title attribute on the button. However, this will style any appearing selection on the button as well. Will not help if you wish the title to appear differently than regular selections.